# Get control focus in other application

Tags: c#, winapi

So far only can know how to get the Handle of the window that is in focus, using this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetFocus();
```

I want to know if, besides that, is there any way to know which control of this application is in focus.

Comment: Well there's [GetGUIThreadInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getguithreadinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN)..

Comment: That assumes that the application uses native controls. **Many modern applications don't use native controls at all**! For example, anything using WPF, Qt, Electron will not have any native controls at all. Native controls are essentially obsolete on Windows, and new code shouldn't normally be worrying about them. For purposes of automation, you may wish to use accessibility APIs, since those are supported by the popular GUI application development frameworks.

Comment: Well, using IAccessible Interface didn't get a result as I expected. 
 I can tell when a control is in focus, but I would like to know the type of that control.
For example, if the focus control is of type Password or Text

Comment: For getting the type of control, use [`GetClassName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname) with the control handle.